# Does queryset.values_list makes another call to db?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say I have an already evaluated queryset.

```py
# queryset is evaluated here
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(name="blabla")

for obj in queryset:
  # do some stuff
```

if I call `.values_list` on this queryset later on, does it make an extra call to the database or fetch the response from the queryset object cache?

```py
obj_map = {k: v in queryset.values_list("id", "name")} # <- does it make a call?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the queries generated after both statements shows that the database is hit a second time. Try this:

```
from django.db import connection


queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(name="blabla")

for obj in queryset:
  # do some stuff
print(len(connection.queries))
>>> 1
obj_map = {k: v in queryset.values_list("id", "name")}
print(len(connection.queries))
>>> 2
```

You can print(connection.queries) instead to see the actual queries being used.

Comment: can we also know what were the queries?

Comment: Yes. I included it in my last statement.
connection.queries returns a list of queries ran by django in a given session

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://github.com/django/django/blob/562898034f65e17bcdd2d951ac5236a1ec8ea690/django/db/models/query.py#L865), the `values_list` function returns a subclass of queryset which clones most of the attributes of the original queryset.

When the queryset is evaluated, it fills its `_result_cache` attribute that is used for methods that does not create new querysets. If this value is None, it means the cache is empty.
Also, [According to the docs](https://github.com/django/django/blob/562898034f65e17bcdd2d951ac5236a1ec8ea690/django/db/models/query.py#L865), the `values_list` function returns a subclass of queryset which clones most of the attributes of the original queryset. However, it doesn't copy the cache:

```py
print(queryset._result_cache)
# [<MyModel: 0>, <MyModel: 2>, <MyModel: 2> ... ]

print(queryset.values_list("id", "name")._result_cache)
# Nothing
```